# How to retrieve name of dynamically created ComboBox in VBA?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, combobox

I would like to reference the value of ComboBoxes I created using a loop, but I do not know what their name is. How can I find their name?

```
Sub addLabel()
Dim theLabel As Object
Dim theRanker As Object
Dim labelCounter As Long
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For labelCounter = 1 To RowCount
    Set theRanker = CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Rating" & labelCounter, True)
    With theRanker
        .Left = 20
        .Width = 150
        .Top = 30 * labelCounter
        .AddItem "Equal Importance"
        .AddItem "Moderate Importance"
        .AddItem "Strong Importance"
        .AddItem "Very Strong Importance"
        .AddItem "Extreme Importance"

    End With
    Set theLabel = CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "CriteriaRank" & labelCounter, True)
    With theLabel
        .caption = Cells(labelCounter, 1).Value
        .Left = 200
        .Width = 150
        .Top = 30 * labelCounter

    End With
Next labelCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `theRanker.Name` ?

Comment: You grab a reference in the code above, why don't you just name them to whatever is convenient?

Comment: Tim, that returned "Rating3," but then when I tried to refer to its value by using Rating3.Value, it said the variable was not defined.

Comment: `theRanker.Value` would do that.  If you really wanted to refer to it by name then you *could* do `CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls(theRanker.Name).Value` but that's kind of circular

Comment: Comintern, it's a loop creating a different amount of comboboxes based on how many variables a user inputs, so I don't think I can name each one.

Comment: Do you need to interact with these controls after you exit the `addLabel` sub?

Comment: Tim, that works in that it returns the value selected in the combobox, but for some reason, it only returns the value of the item in the last combobox. For example, when the user inputs three items, there are three comboboxes that appear. Only the value of the third combobox appears to be saved in theRanker. I need these values of the combobox selections to appear elsewhere.

Comment: They don't need to all be named ahead of time - I would think something like `"Ranker" & labelCounter` would be appropriate\useful.

Comment: @Comintern, how can I name each combobox that is create in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the reference you get from the `.Add` method to name them.  You're already looping through a range of values, so use the loop counter to build object names.  This has the advantage of also having the names corresponding to row that the label originates from:

```
Sub addLabel()
    Dim theLabel As Object
    Dim theRanker As Object
    Dim labelCounter As Long
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    RowCount = Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For labelCounter = 1 To RowCount
        Set theRanker = CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                        "Rating" & labelCounter, True)
        With theRanker
            .Left = 20
            .Width = 150
            .Top = 30 * labelCounter
            .AddItem "Equal Importance"
            .AddItem "Moderate Importance"
            .AddItem "Strong Importance"
            .AddItem "Very Strong Importance"
            .AddItem "Extreme Importance"
            .Name = "Ranker" & labelCounter
        End With
        Set theLabel = CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", _
                       "CriteriaRank" & labelCounter, True)
        With theLabel
            .Caption = Cells(labelCounter, 1).Value
            .Left = 200
            .Width = 150
            .Top = 30 * labelCounter

        End With
    Next labelCounter
End Sub
```

You can use the same method to get the values from them later (or address them by row index by concatenating the name).  You can verify this by creating a UserForm named "CriteriaPairwiseForm", and putting the following code in the form in addition to `Sub addLabel`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    addLabel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    GetValues
End Sub

Private Sub GetValues()

    Dim labelCounter As Long
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim message As String

    RowCount = Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For labelCounter = 1 To RowCount
        message = "Ranker" & labelCounter & " contains:" & vbCrLf & _
                  CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls("Ranker" & labelCounter).Text
        MsgBox message
    Next labelCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: I am unable to see any values from the second code.

Comment: @Lillian - Worked fine when I tested it.  Is the form still open when you're trying to read the values?

Comment: Yes, the form is still open. I do not see any values appear in the immediate window when I change the combobox values.

Comment: @Lillian - I can't replicate that at all, I'd probably need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: the only part of the code I didn't include above is 
`Sub
UserForm_Initialize()
        
      Sheets("Overview").Range("A1").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         addLabel
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
      
  End Sub` So when I run the code, the comboboxes show up, and the selection is made, but the code you provided `CriteriaPairwiseForm.Controls("Ranker" & labelCounter).Text` does not return the selection from the comboboxes like I need-it's blank.

Comment: Where are you calling the test Sub from above? I put a call to `GetValues` in the `UserForm_DblClick` handler and double-clicked the form to test it.

Comment: Even when I do the `UserForm_DblClick` handler, nothing appears. Where am I supposed to be looking for these values?

Comment: They should appear in the immediate window.  Where do you need to use them? After you assign names to them they should be accessible anywhere the form is in scope.

Comment: Nothing appears in the immediate window?

Comment: @Lilian - See the edit.  Run the form, change some of the values, then double-click somewhere else on the form (not on a control).